# How Do i Insert Large Files Into SqLITE DB on low performance PC?

Tags: database, sqlite

My problem is...
When i load a file into my app it takes about ~250 mb but when i try to Insert it on my sqlite database. At the moment of Execute Statement it takes about 750mb. On low performance pc it is a problem, meaby someone know how i can set somethink like max buffer?

Comment: Without any information how your database is structured and any code that shows what your program does when it starts, there is no person in the world who can help you. There is no "slow/fast" switch in SQLite, if that was your hope.

Comment: Also you write "mb" but you probably mean "ms"?

Comment: Hello! Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask